# How to update resources in a running Tomcat application and keep session intact

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat6

I am using IntelliJ 11 to run a spring mvc application in a Tomcat container as I developer.  I have IntelliJ configured so that I can "update resources" to make my jsp changes live without needing a full restart of Tomcat.  However, whenever I update the resources, my session in Tomcat is lost and I must re-login to my app.

Is there a way to get Tomcat to recognize my application resource changes while keeping my session alive?

While I reference IntelliJ in the question, it is really about Tomcat in general.  A way to do this from IntelliJ would be great but any way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat is able to persist sessions across restart. The [Standard Implementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) uses a file called `SESSIONS.ser`. Obviously the objects stored is the session must be `Serializable`.

Comment: Thanks. I found that it was actually some code in the app I was working with that was killing the session.